# Auto "Like" new posts from website (or RSS feed) on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, wordpress, facebook-like

I run a multi-author baseball website (powered by WordPress). The website is set up to automatically post all new blog posts to the website's Facebook page ([Add link to Facebook](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/add-link-to-facebook/) plugin) and automatically tweet the post to the website's Twitter account ([YOURLS: WordPress to Twitter](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/yourls-wordpress-to-twitter/)).

I have also set up automatic posting of my own articles to my personal Facebook profile and Twitter account with [ifttt.com](http://ifttt.com).

The next think I am looking for is, how can I automatically "Like" all posts that are not mine on my personal Facebook profile?

Comment: I am amused when someone down-votes a question simply because they don't know the answer... I've talked with a ton of people outside the SE community who thought this was a great question and by the views, people are obviously searching for the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to do this to some extent using the Facebook API but not as an end user. It is not possible and *the full solution is not within the scope of [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/faq)*.

Consider reading more about using the API at http://graph.facebook.com or http://facebook.stackoverflow.com